# A way to maintain index pointers over a contiguous array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

In Python, I am currently trying to create a per-note frequency visualisation of a specific guitar riff I like

In order to do this and have the points plotted by matplotlib.pyplot I am doing something like this for each note, but will ultimately be summing y-values at specific points for 2 specific frequencies

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_per_beat = 110/60.0 #tempo is 110 bpm, finding no of seconds per beat

#creating range of x values for 8 beats of music, in this case 2 bars
x0 = numpy.linspace(0, t_per_beat * 8, 100)
a = []
#generate y-axis values
for i in x0:
    a.append(numpy.sin(<note_freq> * i)
```

I want the y-axis values to be contiguous like the x-axis, so an array of plotted points is best, but I also want to be able to index specific intervals in the array, down to a granularity of a 'sixteenth note' (t_per_beat/4)

Because the frequency value of my note may increase (so I will need to increase the amount of points in my numpy.linspace array, I cannot be assured the interval of index numbers across the array will be consistent.

Of course splitting into a container of separate arrays (i.e: 2-dimensional list) would be preferable, but where the modelling of the waves means that 2 waves coalesce over beat boundaries, this is not really ideal.

In essence my question is (in absence of a better solution that I haven't thought of), is there logic to store a reference to a piece of data in an array such that when called I can always find the index of said data in the array?

Comment: It's good that you elaborate on the context of your question. I do however have a problem relating the context to the problem of finding the index of an element in an array or list (if that is what this asks about). For a list one can use `.index`. For a numpy array one can use `np.arange(len(a))[a==value]` to find the index. Not sure this is helpful here tough.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to have. Could you please post a sample input and desired output? Because just storing the indices could be done like storing any other kind of values...

Comment: @Scotty1- The input to the program as a whole would be a number of frequencies, and the appropriate start and finish points of those notes in beats per second (multiples of t_per_beat above). Sometimes the start and end would overlap. The expected output would be an array of numbers for the x-axis of a wave graph, simply progressing uniformly from t = 0 to the end of the sequence and an array of y-axis numbers with pointers for each value directly after a time boundary (each time boundary is a multiple of `t_per_beat/4`)

Comment: I forgot to say that the y-axis array are values as a result of sin(frequency * x), but for actual music frequency would be variable (multiple notes decaying at different start points etc.). The intention is to draw a graph of the combined waveform using matplotlib. **having said all that** it has occurred to me that I may have a solution to my own problem which I will test and post if appropriate

Comment: Yeah, but do you have an example? Some executable code etc.

Comment: This is more a problem I anticipated running into as the next step of my program, and I actually because I overlooked a detail in the problem itself in theory I now don't really need the result, I will have to map my x-axis (time) as having as having about 4 times the highest frequency input because if I do it any lower I will miss information on the highest-frequency waves in the plotted result. Hope that makes sense, sorry for the goose chase!

Comment: Hopefully this issue is relevant for people programming for other problems